# Laravel Botman issue - Can't call functions from the same class after nesting inside botman class

Tags: php, laravel, botman

I am trying to use the native buttons and questions feature in Botman inside laravel, however i am struggling to understand how to chain functions without using static functions. I have it working where everything is a static function, however i want to use all the information gathered to send an email.

```
    // initialization function
     public function handle()
     {
         $botman->hears("{message}", function($botman, $message) {
                $this->selectHelpQuery($botman);
         });
     }

     // ask question function 
     public function selectHelpQuery($botman)
     {
         $question = Question::create("How can i help you, would you like to know about the following:")
                ->fallback("Unable to help at this time, please try again later")
                ->callbackId("choose_query")
                ->addButtons([
                    Button::create("button1")->value("val1"),
                    Button::create("button2")->value("val2"),
                ]);
          $botman->ask($question, function (Answer $answer, $botman) {
              // Detect if button was clicked:
              if ($answer->isInteractiveMessageReply()) {
                  if($answer->getValue() == "val1") 
                  {
                      $this->contactFollowUp($botman); //** not working
                  } else {
                      $this->contactNoFollowUp($botman); //** not working
                  }
              }
          });
      }

// other functions.....
```

However without declaring the `contactFollowUp()` function as static and accessing it by using the classname `BotManController::contactFollowUp($botman)` However if i do this i have issues with accessing and setting data for use in other functions. Specifically i get a Method contactFollowUp does not exist error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after finding some github code examples i have managed to work out the issue. It is to do with the way the botman framework is structured. To achive linked conversations you have to use a function from the botman framework called `startConversation()` to envoke this you need to reference `bot` which is from the extended base class Conversation. So you will need an entry point and then the conversation you want to link to like so:
*note you will need the default entry point of run() for each conversation.

```
//BotManController.php
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Chatbot;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;
    use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Actions\Button;
    use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question;

    class BotManController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * start the conversation on intitlization
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            $botman = app("botman");
            $botman->hears("{message}", function($botman, $message) {
                $botman->startConversation(new BotManStart);
            });
            $botman->listen();
        }
    }
```

Then

```
// BotManStart.php    
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Chatbot;

    use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;
    use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Actions\Button;
    use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question;
    use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;

    class BotManStart extends Conversation
    {
        public function run()
        {
            $this->selectHelpQuery();
        }

        public function selectHelpQuery()
        {
            $question = Question::create("How can i help you, would you like to know about the following: ")
                ->fallback("Unable to help at this time, please try again later")
                ->callbackId("choose_query")
                ->addButtons([
                    Button::create("Button 1")->value("button1"),
                    Button::create("Button 2")->value("button2"),
                ]);
            $this->ask($question, function (Answer $answer) {
                if ($answer->isInteractiveMessageReply()) {
                    switch ($answer->getValue()) {
                        case "button1":
                            $this->bot->startConversation(new BotManConversation1());
                            break;
                        case "button2":
                            $this->bot->startConversation(new BotManConversation2());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```